# Client error attempting to change layout margins of a private view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

Hi i have an app which i was running in Xcode 10.4 and application was running fine no errors no issues. I have upgrade my xcode to version 11.0 Now, when i try to run the app it imigiatley crashes with this error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Client error attempting
>   to change layout margins of a private view'

I debug through break point also but i haven't find out why it is showing me this error. I have check Navigation Controller also everthing is fine.It is also showing me this message in console

> Assertion failure in -[_UINavigationBarContentView
>   setLayoutMargins:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3899.13.13/_UINavigationBarContentView.m:703

Can anybody help me how i can get rid of this crash and what is the purpose of this crash?

Comment: Please read this [thread](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/issues/1250).

Comment: Yeah i have go through documents, i want to know everywhere in my app where i programtically set constraint has to apply this condition? @Kamran

Comment: Not everywhere, just when setting `layoutMargins`.

Comment: Actually most of my classes is using Material lib so its difficult to set in every class, its there lib camptability issue, i have downgraded my Xcode version to 10.3 now its running fine. @Kamran

Answer (score 0):

I removed from my code it:

```
 view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

And it helped me

See more https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/issues/1250

Comment: Okay, but unfortunately due to lack of time I downgrade my Xcode, now working fine. @Vasily G

Comment: From which file you have removed this code? .@Vasily G

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code:

```
         if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {           
                let margins = subview.layoutMargins
                subview.frame = CGRect(x: -margins.left, y: -margins.top, width: margins.left + margins.right + subview.frame.size.width, height: margins.top + margins.bottom + subview.frame.size.height)
               } else {
                subview.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
            }
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? Code-only answers aren't very useful for helping others who stumble across the question learn why it works.

Comment: Where is this subView comes from? @A.Guz